# loop through database and narrow search by using the returned id values

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I would like to loop through the database and for every value I would like to narrow the search by using the returned id values in my $idarray in the query. For example let’s say that the user want to search for “molly loves cats” then what I thought I’d do is first I search the database for “molly” and get all the ids and use them in the next search when I search for “loves” and so on. And in the end I would have a list of all the ids that consists of all the three words.

search.php

```
$searchquery= (isset($_POST['searchq']) ? $_POST['searchq'] : NULL);
$q = explode(" ", $searchquery);
foreach($q as $key => $value){
        $in = implode("','", $idarray);
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_mysqli, "SELECT id FROM tbl_headlines WHERE (name LIKE ? OR header LIKE ?) AND id IN('$in')")){
            $searchquerypre = "{$value}%";              
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $searchquerypre);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);

            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
                while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    $idarray[] = array('id'=> $id, 'resultat'=> true);                                              
                }
            }
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 0){
                $idarray[] = array('resultat'=> false);
            }
        }
    }
echo json_encode($idarray);
```

jquery

```
 $('#searchquery').on('keyup', function(){
            var searchquery = $("#searchquery").val();      

            if ($("#searchquery").val().length > 1) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: {searchq: searchquery},
                    success: function(result){
                        console.dir(result);

                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why do it in 3 queries when you can just do it in 1?

Comment: You can search for these words in one query and even set priority for that search

Comment: @Linda : So you didn't say what is really going on wrong with your code?? Seems like you made it alot difficult than it can be done in a very easy way..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on from @scottevans93 answer, you can still approach the same way but instead possibly just consolidate searches in your SQL rather than hard coded loops - also make it an Object so it can be used anywhere.

```
class Search
{
    protected $SearchTerms;
    protected $Sql;

    public function __construct($terms)
    {
         $this->Sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE :search";
         if(is_array($terms))? $this->SearchTerms = $terms : die();
         foreach ($this->SearchTerms as $_term)
         {
             $this->Sql .= " LIKE '%".$_term."%'";
         }
    }

    public function search($input)
    {
         $stmp = (Database:GetInstance()->Prepare($this->Sql))->execute(array(':search' => $input));
         return $stmp->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

Could be used like:

```
$SearchUsers = new Search(array('Kyle','Bob','Jimmy'));
echo 'Users like your search: <br />';
foreach ($SearchUsers->search('Ky') as $_user)
{
    echo $_user . ', ';
}
```

Your output for this example would be 'Kyle, '. - If you had an Object of users, you could pass that into the search terms and then use the `search()` method more efficiently, it all depends on your hierarchy/infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple different ways you can approach your issue without having to use 3 different sets of queries.

One possible implementation, assuming you want to search for the words as individuals you could use `LIKE ''`.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where `text` LIKE '%molly%' and `text` LIKE '%loves%' and `text` LIKE '%cats%';
```